# How can I set maximum length to the part of regular expression?

Tags: regex

`^[A]+(C[A]+)*.....$`  
the periods at the end of my expression are the continuation of my regex
Is it possible to put a max length on this segment (`^[A]+(C[A]+)*`)?

Thank you for any answers

Comment: @dawg That defines the number of times the group can repeat, not the total character length of the match.

Comment: Yes but it s possible to have the total of character length ?

Comment: This is not possible to answer since we need to know the regex flavor. If the regex flavor does not support atomic groups and infinite width lookbehinds, this is not possible to do with just regex and we need the programming language you are using to provide a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can only define lengths for characters and character classes, or for the min/max number of times a group can repeat. So in your example `[A]+` could be scoped to a more precise length, and both the inner starred and outer group could be scoped to a number of repeats.

However, some regular expression libraries have [added push-down automata features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#balancing_group_definition) or language hooks that are not part of traditional regex. Using those types of extensions, it may be possible to count characters and stop matching when a defined limit has been exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you know what must or must not come after the segment you can do this with a positive lookahead, or you can use a lookbehind if supported.

For example, if you wanted to limit the `^[A]+(C[A]+)*` segment of your regex `^[A]+(C[A]+)*.....$` to 5 characters, and you determined that there could not be a `A` or `C` character immediately following, you could use:

```js
const rx = /^(?=.{1,5}[^AC])[A]+(C[A]+)*.....$/;

console.log(rx.test('AAACAxxxxx'));     // true (5 character segment)
console.log(rx.test('AAAACAxxxxx'));    // false (6 character segment)

console.log(rx.test('AAAAACxxxx')); 
// false (5 character segment, but followed by C)
```

The positive lookahead `(?=.{1,5}[^AC])` stipulates that the segment must be between `1` and `5` characters in length, and be followed by a character that is not `A` or `C`.

Looking again at the last example above, the test returns `false` but we want it to return `true` because `'AAAAACxxxx'` *does* match the pattern `^[A]+(C[A]+)*.....$` and the substring `AAAAA` that matches the segment `^[A]+(C[A]+)*` is not over 5 characters in length.

To solve this edge case we can replace `[^AC]` in the lookahead with `([^AC]|C[^A])` so that it allows `C` as the character following the segment as long as it is not followed by `A`.

```js
var rx = /^(?=.{1,5}([^AC]|C[^A]))[A]+(C[A]+)*.....$/;

console.log(rx.test('AAAAACxxxx'));    // true
```

Can you come up with a string that the regex above matches that it shouldn't, or doesn't match that it should?

Answer (score 0):

Let's imaging the max length of the pattern is 10.

With an infinite width lookbehind pattern in .NET and Python PyPi `regex`, or with possessive quantifiers/atomic group in Java you can use:

```js
^A++(CA++)*+(?<=^.{1,10}).*
^(?>A+(CA+)*)(?<=^.{1,10}).*
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3EA%2B%28CA%2B%29*%29%28%3F%3C%3D%5E.%7B1%2C10%7D%29.*&i=MATCH%20%28Up%20to%2010%20chars%20matched%29%0D%0AA123%0D%0AAA123%0D%0AAAA123%0D%0AAACA123%0D%0AAACAA123%0D%0AAACAACA123%0D%0AAACAACAA123%0D%0AAACAACAAA123%0D%0AAACAACAAAA123%0D%0A%0D%0ANo%20match%20%2813%20chars%20matched%29%0D%0AAAAACAAAAACAA123456&o=m) and the [Java regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wJhn2h/1).

The `^A++(CA++)*+(?<=^.{1,10})` regex means that

- `^A++` - one or more `A`s are matched from the start of string (no backtracking allowed into `A++` pattern is allowed due to the possessive quantifier)
- `(CA++)*+` - matches zero or more occurrences (with no backtracking allowed) of `C` and one or more `A`s (again, matched possessively)
- `(?<=^.{1,10})` - a positive lookbehind that requires 1 to 10 chars other than line break chars from the start of string immediately to the left of the current position.

In the .NET regex, that does not support posessive quantifiers, the atomic group (`(?>...)`) is used to prevent backtracking into the patterns inside the group.

If you are using another regex flavor that does not support these constructs, the easiest and most feasible way is to capture the pattern you want to impose a max char limit on and once you obtain a valid match, check the Group 1 value length. That is, something like

```js
const texts = ['AACAACAAAA123','AAAACAAAAACAA123456'];
const re = /^(A+(CA+)*).*$/;
texts.forEach( x => {
    const match = x.match(re)
    if (match) {
      console.log(x, '=>', (match[1].length < 11 ? `${x} is valid!` : `${x} is not valid!`))
    } else { console.log(`No match in ${x}!`) }
  }
)
```